# How do I append successful commands to a file using bash shell?

Tags: bash

There might be an easier way of doing this, I'm going to be running a bunch of commands on a box. I want to keep track of the successful ones so that I can make a script out of it to automate this in the future.

I tried

```
<command> && echo "!!" >> file
```

but the `!!` is printing the line before this one. I've tried a few other things but can't get something to work

Comment: Is there some reason why you can't just look at your history?  As in run `history`.

Comment: or use `script`...then remove the unsuccessfull commandes

Comment: history stores all input, not just succesful commands (or even just exit status)

Comment: @Zoredache Um, I guess but wont this include unsuccessful commands too? and how will I know where the history I want to repeat begins?

Comment: Shouldn't you log the _unsuccessful_ commands instead?

Comment: My suggestion is to simply not run commands that will be unsuccessful.  Then simply remember the first command you want to run.  You could also just keep a [transcript](http://linux.die.net/man/1/script) of everything, and extract the details from the transcript.

Comment: Some other things that don't work: `trap -- 'echo $? $BASH_COMMAND' SIGCHLD` (`$BASH_COMMAND` is already set to the trap command). PROMPT_COMMAND='echo $? $BASH_COMMAND' (`$BASH_COMMAND` is set to the prompt command already), or any prompt/trap hac using history.

Comment: Maybe the best solution here might be to modify the shell coding (yes make your own shell program) to only put the commands in history that were successful.  Seems easier than all the contortions that I have seen here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='[[ $? == 0 ]] && history 1 | sed -r "s/\ +[0-9]+\ +//" >> successful'
```

$PROMPT_COMMAND holds a command which bash executes before issuing a prompt. So what this does is evaluate the exit status of your *previous* command (*after* you press enter to execute your current command, but *before* bash evaluates it), and if it was successful, pull it from your bash history, strip the command number, and put add it to a separate file.

Now you don't have to tack on anything to your commands:

```
echo "exits successfully and will be appended"
ehco "only ends up in bash history"
```

Note that the readline history commands, !! and the rest of its family, only works in interactive shells, you cannot use those in scripts.

Also note that the -r option is gnu sed, bsd sed does not have it.

Comment: +1 this is awesome, although everything is getting appended, even the unsuccessful commands? That's fine I only plan to use the output in the `successful` file to make the script, so I wont be using `!!` for that.

Comment: It helps if you test first :) Replace `[[ $? ]]` with `[[ $? = 0 ]]` to really make it only do succesful ones.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a second shell and strace. In shell 1, use `echo $$` to find the PID of your shell. Then use `strace -f -q -eexecve,exit_group -p that_pid_here` to trace commands and exit statuses. The resulting output can then be mangled into a shellscript afterwards.

Comment: If I do this and try to use sudo in the other shell I get "sudo: must be setuid root". I'm starting to think this probably wasn't one of my best ideas.. lol

Comment: try sudo strace and not strace sudo :)

Comment: @DennisKaarsemaker the problem isn't `sudo strace` the problem is that once `bash_shell_1` is being traced, setuid executables run inside that shell stop functioning right. See http://superuser.com/questions/247888/strange-strace-and-setuid-behaviour-permission-denied-under-strace-but-not-run

Comment: yea I didn't try to run `strace` with sudo, while its running it prevents me from using `sudo` in the second shell

Answer (score 0):

This will do - *note it is ' instead of "*

```
<command> && echo '!!' >> file
```

Comment: This echos the literal string `!!` into the file, rather than `<command>` or the command on the previous line like `"!!"` did.